# How to identify the root from hierarchical data structure using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns: Parent, Parent_Rev, Child, ChildRev. In this structure, Parent serves as a parent node, while Child functions as a child node. Both Parent_Rev and ChildRev capture different revisions of their respective nodes. A Child may appear in the parent column and have it's own child values, indicated in columns Child and Child_Rev.

This hierarchical chain continues until a path is established where a Parent doesn't appear as a Child to any other values.

To generate the desired output, it's necessary to traverse through all the values, identifying all possible levels and combinations until the top node is reached. When checking for possible links, the combination of Node+Rev should be considered unique, rather than just the Node value alone.

**Sample Input Dataframe:**

| Parent | Parent_Rev | Child | Child_REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | B1 | 1 |
| B1 | 1 | C1 | 1 |
| C1 | 1 | D1 | 1 |
| D1 | 1 | E1 | 1 |
| A2 | 1 | B2 | 1 |
| B2 | 1 | C2 | 1 |
| C2 | 1 | C2 | 1 |
| A3 | 1 | B3 | 3 |
| A4 | 1 | B3 | 3 |

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Node1': ['A1','B1','C1','D1','A2','B2','C2','A3','A4'],
                    'Node1_Rev': ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
                    'Node2': ['B1','C1','D1','E1','B2','C2','C2','B3','B3'],
                    'Node2_Rev': ['1','1', '1','1','1','1','1','3','3']
}
)
```

**Sample Output Dataframe:**

| Root | Root_Rev | Parent | Parent_Rev | Child | Child_REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | A1 | 1 | B1 | 1 |
| A1 | 1 | B1 | 1 | C1 | 1 |
| A1 | 1 | C1 | 1 | D1 | 1 |
| A1 | 1 | D1 | 1 | E1 | 1 |
| A2 | 1 | A2 | 1 | B2 | 1 |
| A2 | 1 | B2 | 1 | C2 | 1 |
| A2 | 1 | C2 | 1 | C2 | 1 |
| A3 | 1 | A3 | 1 | B3 | 3 |
| A4 | 1 | A4 | 1 | B3 | 3 |

What are the efficient ways to generate the output for a bigger dataset to update the root and rev for all the parent_child input combinations?

Answer (score 1):

Construct your graph with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org), find the root per subgraph using [`weakly_connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected_components.html) then craft a DataFrame and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
G = nx.from_edgelist((zip(zip(df['Node1'], df['Node1_Rev']),
                          zip(df['Node2'], df['Node2_Rev']))),
                    create_using=nx.DiGraph)

roots = {v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0}

mapper = {}
for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    r = next(iter(c & roots))
    for n in c:
        mapper[n] = r
        
out = (pd.DataFrame(mapper, index=['Root', 'Root_Rev']).T
         .merge(df, left_index=True, right_on=['Node1', 'Node1_Rev'],
                how='right')
      )
```

Output:

```
  Root Root_Rev Node1 Node1_Rev Node2 Node2_Rev
0   A1        1    A1         1    B1         1
1   A1        1    B1         1    C1         1
2   A1        1    C1         1    D1         1
3   A1        1    D1         1    E1         1
4   A2        1    A2         1    B2         1
5   A2        1    B2         1    C2         1
6   A2        1    C2         1    C2         1
7   A3        1    A3         1    B3         3
8   A4        1    A4         1    H4         3
```

Graph:

### [image]

##### Multiple roots per subgraph

If you can have multiple roots in a subgraph, you need to adapt the above code to keep all of them. However the exact behavior is undefined (you could chose to collect them in a list, explode the rows…).

Here is a generic way to associate a node with only its actual roots:

```
G = nx.from_edgelist((zip(zip(df['Node1'], df['Node1_Rev']),
                          zip(df['Node2'], df['Node2_Rev']))),
                    create_using=nx.DiGraph)

roots = {v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0}

mapper = {}
for n in G:
    a = nx.ancestors(G, n) & roots
    mapper[n] = list(zip(*a)) if len(a)>1 else next(iter(a), n)
        
out = (pd.DataFrame(mapper, index=['Root', 'Root_Rev']).T
         .merge(df, left_index=True, right_on=['Node1', 'Node1_Rev'],
                how='right')
         #.explode(['Root', 'Root_Rev']) # optional
      )
```

Output:

```
        Root Root_Rev Node1 Node1_Rev Node2 Node2_Rev
0         A1        1    A1         1    B1         1
1         A1        1    B1         1    C1         1
2         A1        1    C1         1    D1         1
3         A1        1    D1         1    E1         1
4         A2        1    A2         1    B2         1
5         A2        1    B2         1    C2         1
6         A2        1    C2         1    C2         1
7         A3        1    A3         1    B3         3
8         A5        1    A4         1    B3         3
9         A5        1    A5         1    A4         1
10  (A5, A3)   (1, 1)    B3         3    B4         4 # this node has 2 roots
```

Output with `explode`:

```
   Root Root_Rev Node1 Node1_Rev Node2 Node2_Rev
0    A1        1    A1         1    B1         1
1    A1        1    B1         1    C1         1
2    A1        1    C1         1    D1         1
3    A1        1    D1         1    E1         1
4    A2        1    A2         1    B2         1
5    A2        1    B2         1    C2         1
6    A2        1    C2         1    C2         1
7    A3        1    A3         1    B3         3
8    A5        1    A4         1    B3         3
9    A5        1    A5         1    A4         1
10   A5        1    B3         3    B4         4 # exploded
10   A3        1    B3         3    B4         4 # into 2 rows
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Different Node1 values with same Node2 populates the same root in the output. But it should have different roots as they are not forming the hierarchy. When I change the last value of Node2 from H4 to B3(edited the dataframe), the root value is shown as A3 for last two rows instead of A3 and A4 as roots.

Comment: @Osceria my above code made the hypothesis that there is only one root per subgraph. If you have more then the behavior needs to be clarified. What happens for instance of you were merging B2/1 B3/3 as a single row (let's say both become B2/1)? Should this duplicate the row with B2/1->C2/1 to have the two roots?